# ¿Como eliminar los objetos de una clase dentro de vector en C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

mi duda es que quiero eliminar los datos que se encuentran en un arreglo con una clase personalizada,intente con un destructor, pero al momento de llamarlo me cierra el programa

esta es la clase creada, con una parte de los parametros

```
class Libro {
private:
    string Titulo;
    string Autor;
    int Pagina;
    int Age;
    int Edicion;
    string ISBN;

public:
    Libro();//constructor predeterminado
    ~Libro();//destructor
    Libro(string, string, int, int, int);//constructor princopal
    Libro(string, string, int);

    void setTitulo(string);
    void setAutor(string);
    void setPagina(int);
    void setAge(int);
    void setEdicion(int);

    string getTitulo();
    string getAutor();
    int getPagina();
    int getAge();
    int getEdicion();

    void internalISBN();
    string getISBN();
    void mostrar();
};

Libro::Libro() {
}

Libro::~Libro() {

}
```

Comment: ¿ Que es para tí un *arreglo* (en el título dices `vector`) ?¿ Que es para tí `eliminar los datos` ? Creo que el código en el que haces la *liberación* sería mucho mas descriptivo que colocar la definición de la clase, salvo que estés 100% seguro de que el problema esté en la propia clase.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la clase vector de la stl. Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con datos int, la única diferencia es que en tu programa tendrás que sustituir los datos int por el tipo de la clase que quieras (en tu caso Libro):

```
// erasing from vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;

    // insertamos valores
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Eliminamos el sexto elemento : " << std::endl;
    // eliminamos el sexto elemento
    myvector.erase(myvector.begin() + 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    // eliminamos los primeros 3 elementos
    std::cout << "Eliminamos los primeros 3 elementos" << std::endl;
    myvector.erase(myvector.begin(), myvector.begin() + 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "myvector contiene";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < myvector.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No veo como un vector de enteros soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta ...

Comment: @eferion solo es un ejemplo

Comment: Los ejemplos deben tener un sentido... si yo te cuento que mi coche tiene problemas y me empiezas a hablar de gallinas...

Comment: El quiere eliminar fácilmente datos en un vector, yo le estoy enseñando un ejemplo de como hacerlo pero le explico que el debe sustituir el int por el dato que el necesite, no veo donde está el problema, pero gracias de todas formas